# Ruby: Reading Unsaved Text File

Tags: ruby, windows, file, filesystems

I have a RFID scanner program in Windows writing its results to a sample text file.  However the program does NOT save the file.  Is there any way in Ruby that I can read in these changes made to the text file even though they have not been committed?

Comment: Even if the results have got as far as a Windows file buffer, this is not going to be in memory that a separate Ruby process can access. Is the RFID scanner program the Ruby project you want to debug? If so, you may be able to re-phrase this question asking why specific code that should write a file is failing to do so . . .

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Neil.  No, I don't need to debug the RFID program.  It's a closed source client that I am forced to work with due to the hardware we use.  It has to run for the scanner to work at all and there is a feature to forward the tag data to another application (like Notepad) but the client doesn't force Notepad to save itself, hence my question.  I guess the next idea is to figure out a way to have Notepad save itself so Ruby can then read the file.

Comment: If the text is getting into Notepad, you may be able to use windows features (OLE) to have Ruby talk to Notepad and inspect the contents. You may also be able to have a Ruby process be the target app. I don't know enough Ruby OLE, but you may get further looking at e.g. http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/lib_windows.html

Answer (score 3):

.                            You can not                                              .

Answer (score 0):

Can the RFID program be setup to send it's data to any arbitrary program? Because if so, then I'd say your best bet is to start by writing a program that it can send to that would do something sensible with the data (like write it to a file), instead of using Notepad as part of your process.